# How can I avoid quality problems due to 3D in Flash CS4?

Tags: vector, flash-cs4, antialiasing

I am currently using Flash CS4 to make some sprites. The sprite is completely vector based and should therefore have good quality. However, once I apply some 3D properties to anything, it becomes very aliased. Is there some quality setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH;`

High quality is the default, but if it isn't with you for some reason, that line should and fix it. It might slow it down some though you know. Especially if you have a lot to anti-alias. (There's also a "best" quality which smooths non-static bitmaps if you want to try that.)